Restore database with compatibility level lower than 90 in SQL 2019 or 2022?
Has anyone restored a database with a compatibility level lower than 90 in SQL 2019 or 2022? The documentation says it needs to be 90 or more recent, but I managed to restore a database with compatibility level 80 without any issues. Have you encountered any problems?
My database with compatibility level 80 (SQL 2000) is in a SQL Server 2008 instance. Why I was able to restore it?

Restore in SQL Server 2022 (automatically upgraded to a compatibility level of 100 after restore)


Did you run a DBCC CHECKDB after the migration?

What documentation are you referring to? The important thing will be that it understands the file format - and this is only dependent on the SQL Server version that created it. Not the compatibility level. Though not having support for compat level 2000 will mean that you may encounter a lot of breaking changes if you were using deprecated features.
